# How to build the string for streamwriter method dynamically

Tags: c#-4.0

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM masterdata", conn);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
                log.Write(reader[0] + "|" + reader[1] + "|" + reader[2] + "|" + reader[3] + "|" +
                    reader[4] + "|" + reader[5] + "|" + reader[6] + "|" + reader[7] + "|" +
                    reader[8] + "|" + reader[9] + "|" + reader[10] + "|" + reader[11] + "|" +
                    reader[12] + "|" + reader[13] + "|" + reader[14] + "|" + reader[15] + Environment.NewLine);
                log.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to recreate what is inside the log.write method dynamically? I want to create a class that will accept a number and recreate a string to used on the write method. Ex. I passed 4 then it will create something like this.

```
log.Write(reader[0] + "|" + reader[1] + "|" + reader[2] + "|" + reader[3] + Environment.NewLine);
```

Thank you for anyone that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the `Aggregate` extension method with `Take`.  For example:

```
        int n = 4;
        string s = reader.Take(4).Aggregate(string.Empty, (s1, i) => s1 + "|" + i);
```